# Flutter code creating laggy animation. What is wrong here?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, accelerometer, flutter-animation

I have created a flutter widget that moves the circle with accelerometer. It is very laggy as I have to use setState to change the position of the circle when phone is moved. Is there an alternative to creating this?

I have used AnimatedBuilder here but not sure how that can change the position of circle when device is moved smoothly.

```dart
class _AnimationWidgetState extends State<AnimationWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animeController;
  Animation _anime;
  double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animeController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));
    _anime = Tween(begin: 0.5, end: 0.5).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animeController, curve: Curves.ease));
    accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      var a = ((event.x * 100).round() / 100).clamp(-1.0, 1.0) * -1;
      var b = ((event.y * 100).round() / 100).clamp(-1.0, 1.0);
      if ((x - a).abs() > 0.02 || (y - b).abs() > 0.02) {
        setState(() {
          x = a; y = b;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _animeController.forward();
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animeController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                _anime.value * width * x, _anime.value * height * y, 0.0),
            child: Center(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 15.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Animation is not at all smooth. This is because I have to use setState but the movement of circle is working as desired.

Comment: Are you running it on debug mode? Did you try release mode? Try `flutter run --release` or simply `flutter build`

Comment: how often `build` method is called? why the threshold is `0.02`? and why do you call `_animeController.forward();` inside it (and with constant 2 seconds duration)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of using `AnimationController` is to listen to its events - that's what `AnimatedBuilder` does and rebuilds its subtree accordingly.

I will post here my overall recommendations on what to change in the code.

---

Remove `setState` - that's what makes your entire layout rebuild all over again, i.e. lags.

Also trigger `_animeController` listeners, i.e. AnimatedBuilder in your case - to rebuild itself.

```dart
accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
  var a = ((event.x * 100).round() / 100).clamp(-1.0, 1.0) * -1;
  var b = ((event.y * 100).round() / 100).clamp(-1.0, 1.0);
  if ((x - a).abs() > 0.02 || (y - b).abs() > 0.02) {
    x = a; y = b;
    _animeController.value = _animeController.value; // Trigger controller's listeners
  }
});
```

---

Start animation in `initState`, instead of `build`. This is the second thing that produces lags in your case. `.forward` triggers rebuild of your widgets, which leads to an infinite loop.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _animeController.forward();
}
```

---

Use `child` property of your `AnimatedBuilder` to save up resources on rebuilding the avatar block every time. Also I'm not sure what `Scaffold` is here for - let's remove it if it's not needed.

```dart
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _animeController,
  builder: (context, child) => Transform(
    transform: Matrix4.translationValues(_anime.value * width * x, _anime.value * height * y, 0.0),
    child: child,
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 15.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ),
  ),
);
```

---

Follow [Official Animations Tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) to master Flutter animations.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Removed scaffold, removed setState, have put forward in initState. The animation is now better but still not good enough and lags. Like it cannot be updated soon enough with each time accelerometer event value is changed.

Comment: @ShikhirAggarwal try removing `if` condition in `accelerometerEvents.listen`. This could be limiting the update frequency.

Comment: Yes removed it but still it is laggy. But anyways it is very better than before and little bit even better in release mode. So overall its good thanks

Comment: @ShikhirAggarwal glad to help!